# How to lay out two button in two side in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my application screen, i have two buttons. one is Activate and another is About. I want Activate in left side and About in right side and both will be same size. I write the below code:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60px"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnActivate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="Activate"
    android:textColor="#000000"
>
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:text="About"
    android:textColor="#000000"
>
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now both the button is coming with same size. But i want them with some specific width like 60 dp. How can i do that??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have set 0dp on your width attribute. Your buttons will not be visible this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting android:layout_weight to 1 for both buttons, you ask the buttons to expand and cover the whole width of the layout with equal width (weight).

Remove the android:layout_weight attribute and set android:layout_width to the desired width.

Comment: yes..i removed that. And using android:layout_alignParentRight and android:layout_alignParentLeft i solved this issue.